# HTML/CSS dropdown menu hiding other dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

this is my website that I am developing, and I trying to develop a calculator which depending on the subject and equation your are trying to use, the calculator will give you an answer.

I made two dropdown menus, however, when I hover over the "Physics" menu, for some reason the "Maths" menu is covered. Also, the list for "Physics" is a bit too long and I wanted to make a scroll bar, but I don't know how to.

I tried to look on w3schools and other resources, but I couldn't find a solutions which solved my problem.

```css
.redirect:hover{background-color:#aac8ff;}
div{background-color:#ccd9fb;}
h1{font-size: 20px; padding-left:10px;}
.dropdown-content a{background-color:#aac8ff}
.container:hover .dropdown-content{display:block}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #99b7ff;}
li.container{display:inline}
li{display:inline;}

body {
    background-color: #eefbfb;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

.top h1, .top ul{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.redirect{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    width:125px;
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid #eefbfb;
    padding: 14px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:right;
}

.dropdown-content{
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
    min-width:auto;
    max-width:155px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color:#99b7ff;
}

.dropdown-content a{
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
            <div class="top">
                <h1>123Calculator</h1></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="redirect" href="equations.html">Equations</a></li>
                    <li class="container">
                        <a class="redirect" href="physics.html">Physics</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="Physics/1.PhotNEnLvl.html">Phontons and Energy levels</a>
                            <a href="Physics/2.Waves.html">Waves</a>
                            <a href="Physics/3.Mech.html">Mechanics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/4.Mat.html">Materials</a>
                            <a href="Physics/5.Elect.html">Electricity</a>
                            <a href="Physics/6.CircMot.html">Circular Motion</a>
                            <a href="Physics/7.SimpHarMot.html">Simple Harmonic Motion</a>
                            <a href="Physics/8.TherPhy.html">Thermal Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/9.GravFie.html">Gravitational Fields</a>
                            <a href="Physics/10.ElecFieNCap.html">Electric Fields and Capacitors</a>
                            <a href="Physics/11.MagFie.html">Magnetic Fields</a>
                            <a href="Physics/12.NukePhy.html">Nuclear Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/13.Astro.html">Astrophysics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/14.MedPhy.html">Medical Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/15.EngPhy.html">Engineering Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/16.TurnPInPhys.html">Turning Points in Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/17.Electronics.html">Electronics</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container">
                        <a class="redirect" href="maths.html">Maths</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="Maths/1.AlgExpr.html">Algebraic Expressions</a>
                            <a href="Maths/2.EqNIn.html">Equations and Inequalities</a>
                            <a href="Maths/3.SkeCur.html">Sketching Curves</a>
                            <a href="Maths/4.ymaxc.html">Equations of Straight Lines</a>
                            <a href="Maths/5.circles.html">Circles</a>
                            <a href="Maths/6.trig.html">Trigonometry</a>
                            <a href="Maths/7.ExpNLog.html">Exponentials and Logarithms</a>
                            <a href="Maths/8.Diff.html">Differentiation</a>
                            <a href="Maths/9.Integ.html">Integration</a>
                            <a href="Maths/10.vect.html">Vectors</a>
                            <a href="Maths/11.proof.html">Proof</a>
                            <a href="Maths/12.kinem.html">Kinematics</a>
                            <a href="Maths/13.forces.html">Forces</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a lot of errors in the code. Like in `li`, you gave css as `display: inline;`; and the sub-menu you didn't give any positions like `position: absolute;`

I have applied my changes below.

Thanks me later.

```css
.redirect:hover{background-color:#aac8ff;}
div{background-color:#ccd9fb;}
h1{font-size: 20px; padding-left:10px;}
.dropdown-content a{background-color:#aac8ff}
.container:hover .dropdown-content{transform: scaleY(1);}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #99b7ff;}
li.container{display:inline-block;position:relative;}
li{display:inline-block;}

body {
    background-color: #eefbfb;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

.top h1, .top ul{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.redirect{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    width:125px;
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid #eefbfb;
    padding: 14px;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float:right;
}

.dropdown-content{
    z-index:1;
    min-width:auto;
    max-width:155px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color:#99b7ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left:0;
  transition: .3s linear;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a{
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
            <div class="top">
                <h1>123Calculator</h1></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="container">
                        <a class="redirect" href="physics.html">Physics</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="Physics/1.PhotNEnLvl.html">Phontons and Energy levels</a>
                            <a href="Physics/2.Waves.html">Waves</a>
                            <a href="Physics/3.Mech.html">Mechanics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/4.Mat.html">Materials</a>
                            <a href="Physics/5.Elect.html">Electricity</a>
                            <a href="Physics/6.CircMot.html">Circular Motion</a>
                            <a href="Physics/7.SimpHarMot.html">Simple Harmonic Motion</a>
                            <a href="Physics/8.TherPhy.html">Thermal Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/9.GravFie.html">Gravitational Fields</a>
                            <a href="Physics/10.ElecFieNCap.html">Electric Fields and Capacitors</a>
                            <a href="Physics/11.MagFie.html">Magnetic Fields</a>
                            <a href="Physics/12.NukePhy.html">Nuclear Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/13.Astro.html">Astrophysics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/14.MedPhy.html">Medical Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/15.EngPhy.html">Engineering Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/16.TurnPInPhys.html">Turning Points in Physics</a>
                            <a href="Physics/17.Electronics.html">Electronics</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container">
                        <a class="redirect" href="maths.html">Maths</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="Maths/1.AlgExpr.html">Algebraic Expressions</a>
                            <a href="Maths/2.EqNIn.html">Equations and Inequalities</a>
                            <a href="Maths/3.SkeCur.html">Sketching Curves</a>
                            <a href="Maths/4.ymaxc.html">Equations of Straight Lines</a>
                            <a href="Maths/5.circles.html">Circles</a>
                            <a href="Maths/6.trig.html">Trigonometry</a>
                            <a href="Maths/7.ExpNLog.html">Exponentials and Logarithms</a>
                            <a href="Maths/8.Diff.html">Differentiation</a>
                            <a href="Maths/9.Integ.html">Integration</a>
                            <a href="Maths/10.vect.html">Vectors</a>
                            <a href="Maths/11.proof.html">Proof</a>
                            <a href="Maths/12.kinem.html">Kinematics</a>
                            <a href="Maths/13.forces.html">Forces</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this looks better as well!